# Deriving a list from a given list with additional elements

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, java-8

I am maintaining a class to keep all the fields externalized. A sample class which holds several such values and their collections is:

```
public static class State {
    public static final String DRAFT = "DRAFT";
    public static final String APPROVED = "APPROVED";
    public static final String RECEIVED = "RECEIVED";
    public static final String PENDING = "PENDING";

    public static List<String> IMMUTABLE_STATES = Arrays.asList(APPROVED,RECEIVED);
    public static List<String> IRREVERSIBLE_STATES = Arrays.asList(DRAFT,RECEIEVED,PENDING);
}
```

As it can be seen that `IRREVERSIBLE_STATES` has all the fields (states) which `IMMUTABLE_STATES` has. Plus, it has some extra of its own, `PENDING` in this case.

Is there a way to elegantly initialize the second list so that it directly takes the values from the first list instead of declaring all the common states again? Do I have to write a method to achieve this? Can't it be done in one line as an initializer?

Comment: how about `List<String> IRREVERSIBLE_STATES  = new ArrayList<>(IMMUTABLE_STATES )` ? Btw, I would use an `enum` here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using streams?

```
public static List<String> LIST1 = Arrays.asList("1", "2");
public static List<String> LIST2 = Stream.concat(LIST1.stream(), Arrays.asList("3", "4").stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Also, your "states" feel like they should be `enums`, not Strings.

Comment: nice. Streams are nice

Answer (score 1):

Although concatenating streams would work here,
a simpler solution is using a static initializer:

```
public static List<String> IRREVERSIBLE_STATES = new ArrayList<>(IMMUTABLE_STATES);
static {
    IRREVERSIBLE_STATES.addAll(Arrays.asList(DRAFT, PENDING));
}
```